# I can't run tests with JUnit Jupyter. Hangs on message "Resolving launch configuration". How to fix it?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit

I'm using the Junit Jupiter. I installed by vscode. This is my lib junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.0.jar in vs code :

[image: lib junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.0.jar]

My files are :

Main.java

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
        Compromisso compromisso = new Compromisso("Matheus", "31/08/2022");
        agenda.addCompromissoPeriodico(compromisso, 7,3);
        for (int i = 0; i < agenda.getAgenda().size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(agenda.getAgenda().get(i).getNome());
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            System.out.print(agenda.getAgenda().get(i).getDataCompromisso().getData());
        }

    }
}
```

Agenda.java

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import static java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;

public class Agenda {


    private static ArrayList<Compromisso> agenda = new ArrayList<>();
    private static GregorianCalendar gc;

    public void addCompromisso(Compromisso compromisso) {
        agenda.add(compromisso);
    }

    public void addCompromissoPeriodico(Compromisso compromisso, int repetirAcada, int numeroRepeticoes) {

        gc = iniciarCalendar(compromisso.getDataCompromisso());

        for (int i = 0; i <= numeroRepeticoes; i++) {
            addCompromisso(compromisso);
            gc.add(DAY_OF_MONTH, repetirAcada);
            compromisso.getDataCompromisso().setData(gc.getTime());
        }
    }

    public void vizualizarCompromissos(String diaInicial, String diaFinal) throws ParseException {
        DataC dataInicial;
        DataC dataFinal = new DataC(diaFinal);

        for (Compromisso compromisso : agenda) {
            dataInicial = new DataC(diaInicial);
            gc = iniciarCalendar(dataInicial);

            while (dataInicial.getData().equals(dataFinal.getData())) {
                if (compromisso.getDataCompromisso().getData() == dataInicial.getData()) {
                    compromisso.imprimirCompromisso();
                }
                gc.add(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private GregorianCalendar iniciarCalendar(DataC data) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTime(data.getData());
        return gc;
    }


    //#region Getter

    public static ArrayList<Compromisso> getAgenda() {
        return agenda;
    }


    //#endregion
}
```

Compromisso.java

```
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Compromisso {

    //#region Atributos
    private static String nome;
    private static DataC dataCompromisso;

    //#endregion


    //#region Construtores

    /**
     * Inicializa o objeto compromisso a Partir de uma String nome e uma String com a data do compromisso.
     *
     * @param name            Espera uma String para atribuir ao objeto compromisso
     * @param dataCompromisso Espera uma String no formato dd/MM/yyyy para atribuir ao objeto compromisso
     */
    public Compromisso(String name, String dataCompromisso) throws ParseException {
        init(name, dataCompromisso);
    }

    /**
     * Inicializa o objeto compromisso com o valor de nome "Não Iniciado" e a Data "01/01/2022"
     */
    public Compromisso() throws ParseException {
        init("Não Iniciado", "01/01/2022");
    }

    //#endregion


    //region Métodos


    /**
     * Método privado utilizado para auxiliar na atribuição dos construtores
     *
     * @param nome            Espera uma String para atribuir o nome.
     * @param dataCompromisso Espera uma String no formato dd/MM/yyyy.
     * @throws ParseException Lança uma excessão caso o formato não corresponda ao esperado.
     */
    private void init(String nome, String dataCompromisso) throws ParseException {
        Compromisso.nome = nome;
        Compromisso.dataCompromisso = new DataC(dataCompromisso);
    }

    /**
     * Método utilizado para imprimir na tela, os dados do compromisso no formato String
     */
    public void imprimirCompromisso() {
        System.out.println(nome);
        System.out.println(dataCompromisso.dataEmString());
    }
    //#endregion

    //#Region Getters

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public DataC getDataCompromisso() {
        return dataCompromisso;
    }

    //#endregion
}
```

DataC.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DataC {
    
    //#region Atributos
    private Date data;

    //#endregion

    //#region Construtores


    /**
     *  Inicializa o objeto Data, a partir da String com a data correspondente
     * @param inputUsuario Espera uma String no formato dd/MM/yyyy
     * @throws ParseException Lança excessão caso o formato do input esteja fora do padrão dd/MM/yyyy
     */
    DataC(String inputUsuario) throws ParseException {
        init(inputUsuario);
    }


    /**
     * Inicializa o objeto data com o valor "01/01/2022 caso não seja passado nenhum parâmetro"
     */
    DataC() throws ParseException {
        init("01/01/2022");
    }

    //#endregion


    //#region Métodos

    /**
     *  Método privado utilizado para iniciar os construtores
     * @param inputUsuario Espera uma String no formato "dd/MM/yyyy"
     * @throws ParseException Lança excessão caso o formato do input esteja fora do padrão dd/MM/yyyy
     */
    private void init(String inputUsuario) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        this.data = sdf1.parse(inputUsuario);
    }

    /**
     * Método que converte a variavel date para String
     * @return Retorna uma String no formato "dd/MM/yyyy"
     */
    public String dataEmString() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return dateFormat.format(this.data);
    }

    //#endregion


    //#region Getters & Setters

    public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Date data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    //#endregion

}
```

TestAgenda.java

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.text.ParseException;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestAgenda {

    private static Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
    private static Compromisso compromisso;

    static {
        try {
            compromisso = new Compromisso("Aniversario", "20/04/2003");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void insereNaLista() {

        agenda.addCompromisso(compromisso);
        assertEquals(Agenda.getAgenda().get(0).getNome(), "Aniversario");
    }


}
```

TestCompromisso.java

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.text.ParseException;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestCompromisso {
    @Test
    public void criarCerto() throws ParseException {
        Compromisso compromisso = new Compromisso("Meu aniversario", "20/04/2003");
        assertEquals(compromisso.getNome(), "Meu aniversario");
        assertEquals(compromisso.getDataCompromisso().dataEmString(), "20/04/2003");
    }

    @Test
    public void criarCertoVazio() throws ParseException {
        Compromisso compromisso = new Compromisso();
        assertEquals(compromisso.getNome(), "Não Iniciado");
        assertEquals(compromisso.getDataCompromisso().dataEmString(), "01/01/2022");
    }

}
```

TestData.java

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.text.ParseException;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestData {
    @Test
    void imprimirCorreto() throws ParseException {
        DataC dataUsuario = new DataC("20/04/2003");
        String dataConvertida = dataUsuario.dataEmString();
        assertEquals(dataConvertida, "20/04/2003");
    }

    @Test
     void criarData() throws ParseException {
        DataC dataUsuario = new DataC("20/04/2003");
        assertEquals(dataUsuario.dataEmString(), "20/04/2003");
    }

    @Test
    void criarDataVazia() throws ParseException {
        DataC dataUsuario = new DataC();
        assertEquals(dataUsuario.dataEmString(), "01/01/2022");
    }

}
```

Please don't worry with the code qualit.

Whe i run the code workink:

[image: Run the code]

But if i run the tests hangs on message "Resolving launch configuration" like the image below:

[image: Resolving launch configuration]

I tried a lot of thing. Downgrade extensions and packejes, conect in anoter network, change the folder and paths. I tried install the *.jar from other place but I can't run in vs code. I verify and change references. Nothing worked.

I using Windows 10 in the last update version, 64 bits.

Comment: Is **launch.json** configured? Can the content be displayed?

Comment: There isn't a  launch.json configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, you seem to be experiencing an issue [similar to this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/1481). If your extension is not to the latest version (0.37.1), then please update it and reload vscode, as that issue was just fixed and released yesterday. For me, I also had to update vscode in order for it to work, so you may need to do that as well. Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and tried a lot of things to fix it.  When I built the project, the tests ran, but if I tried to click the inline runner button or use the "Testing" tab of VSCode, I got an infinitely loading "Resolving Launch Configuration" notification.  I am on the latest released update of the Test Runner (v0.40), using Gradle.  One thing I tried was looking at the "Runtime Status" tab within the "Test Runner for Java" extension page.  The tab contained a list of "Uncaught Errors", which showed an error which read `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')`.  I didn't think much of it at the time, but I later looked into the "settings.json" file and found a variable called `name`, which was currently set to `null`.  I changed it to the empty object `{}` instead, and the tests ran successfully.